# How to clone an MTPFS partition of a mounted Android phone?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, dd, android, mtp

Using `mtpfs` I've mounted a Samsung Galaxy S5 and I need to make an image of its root partition. I want to use `dd` or the like, but nothing seems to be able to detect/reference an MTP and/or FUSE partition, whether it be mounted or not. But there's no apparent way to do this.

How do I reference an `mtpfs` partition to clone it, and create an image I can mount as `ext2` for example? I am using Mint 17.1 and the device is a Lolipop Android OS.

Ultimately I need to run data recovery tools on the partition, so I need to copy the "empty" segments of the FAT more than the populated areas.

Answer (score 3):

MTPFS is a filesystem, not a partition. Your computer makes requests like “give me the file at this location”, not “give me the content of this block”. How the files are stored on the other side is not visible through MTP; it could be a gnome typing replies very very fast.

If you want to make a backup of what you can see over MTP, just back up the files. That's all MTP gives you. Deleted areas are very far beyond your reach there.

If you want to make a backup of the parts that you don't see over MTPFS, you need some other way of accessing the device. I think [adb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#ADB) access gives you access to more things than ADB, but on the Galaxy S5, like on most Android phones, you only get unprivileged ADB access, so there are still many things you can't access, including the unused disk space.

In order to run this data recovery, you need to have root access. There are two ways to do that. One way is to install an alternate system image. I think the Galaxy S5 lets you do that, but that process wipes the internal storage, so that's not good for you. The other way is to exploit a bug in your version of Android, if it has a known bug.

If you haven't already rooted the phone, and Samsung hasn't made any implementation mistake, then you're not supposed to be able to do what you're trying to do. That's considered a security feature: you can't extract system files from the device. The only option is to exploit a mistake that Samsung made, if you can find one, or fairly expensive hardware attacks like unsoldering the flash memory. Sorry.

Comment: You know, you're absolutely right and I didn't think about it that way. This is more like an NTFS mount than a mounted partition. The permissions disallow violation of the state of the device... so I'm locked in user space then. Ah, gotcha.